# XML Output Table's Values

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

What i have to change in my code to have an output like this?

```
<Team Name="x">
  <Nationality nationality="a">
   <Player name="abc"/>  
   <Player name="def"/>  
  </Nationality>

  <Nationality nationality="b">
   <Player name="xyz"/>  
  </Nationality>
</Team>
```

At this moment i have the following code:

```
SELECT XMLElement("Team", XMLATTRIBUTES(TeamName as "Name"),
(SELECT XMLElement("Nationality", XMLAttributes(nationality AS "Nationality"), 
        XMLAgg(XMLElement("Player", name)))
FROM players
WHERE team_id = 03111 
GROUP BY nationality 
))
from teams
```

The "middle select" returns the results that i want, but in many lines.
I want all in a single line, i thought if i put a 'general' XMLElement it works, but returns this error:

> 1427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

How can i resolve it?

PS: I have two tables, Players and Teams. The nationality it's not a table, but an attribute of Players

Answer (score 0):

Nest your XMLAGG and XMLELEMENT calls, e.g. (for EMP table)

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (
          CONTENT
          XMLELEMENT (
             "Department",
                XMLAGG (
                   XMLELEMENT (
                      "Job",
                       XMLATTRIBUTES (job AS "Job"),
                       XMLAGG (
                          XMLELEMENT (
                             "Employee",
                              XMLATTRIBUTES (ename AS "Name"))))))
          AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 3) xml
FROM   emp e INNER JOIN dept d ON (d.deptno = e.deptno)
WHERE  d.dname = 'SALES'
GROUP BY e.job;
```

Returns....

```
<Department>
   <Job Job="CLERK">
      <Employee Name="JAMES"/>
   </Job>
   <Job Job="MANAGER">
      <Employee Name="BLAKE"/>
   </Job>
   <Job Job="SALESMAN">
      <Employee Name="WARD"/>
      <Employee Name="ALLEN"/>
      <Employee Name="TURNER"/>
      <Employee Name="MARTIN"/>
   </Job>
</Department>
```